# How do I populate upper.tri of matrix with matched integers from the lower.tri?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

**Issue**

I have a dataframe of familial relationships coded with integers, where `R01` is the relationship of `person N` to `person 1`, `R02` their relationship to `person 2` etc.

However, only the `lower.tri` of each family matrix is coded, so I am trying to write a function to `match` the correct relationship in the `upper.tri`.

**Relationships**

The relationships are coded in integers as follows:

`1` = Spouse, `2` = Cohabiting partner, `3` = Son/daughter, `4` = Step son/daughter, `5` = Foster child, `6` = Son-in-law/daughter-in-law, `7` = Parent/guardian, `8` = Step-parent, `9` = Foster parent, `10` = Parent-in-law, `11` = Brother/sister,  `12` = Step-brother/sister, `13` = Foster brother/sister, `14` = Brother/sister-in-law, `15` = Grand-child, `16` = Grand-parent, `17` = Other relative, `18` = Other non-relative.

thus the relationships are:

`rel = c("1" = 1, "2" = 2, "3" = 7, "4" = 8, "5" = 9, "6" = 10, "7" = 3, "8" = 4, "9" = 5, "10" = 6, "11" = 11, "12" = 12, "13" = 13, "14" = 14, "15" =  16, "16" = 15, "17" = 17, "18" = 18)`

**Example Data**

```
   household person R01 R02 R03 R04 R05 R06
1          1      1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2          1      2   1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3          1      3   3   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
4          1      4   3   3  11  NA  NA  NA
5          2      1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
6          2      2   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
7          2      3  15   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
8          3      1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
9          3      2  18  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10         4      1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
11         5      1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
12         5      2   5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

**Required Output**

```
   household person R01 R02 R03 R04 R05 R06
1          1      1  NA   1   7   7  NA  NA
2          1      2   1  NA   7   7  NA  NA
3          1      3   3   3  NA  11  NA  NA
4          1      4   3   3  11  NA  NA  NA
5          2      1  NA   1  16  NA  NA  NA
6          2      2   3  NA   1  NA  NA  NA
7          2      3  15   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
8          3      1  NA  18  NA  NA  NA  NA
9          3      2  18  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
10         4      1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
11         5      1  NA   9  NA  NA  NA  NA
12         5      2   5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

**Example Code**

```
df <- data.frame(household = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,5),
                 person = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2),
                 R01 = c(NA, 1, 3, 3, NA, 3, 15, NA, 18, NA, NA, 5),
                 R02 = c(NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA, 3, rep(NA, 5)),
                 R03 = c(rep(NA,3), 11, rep(NA, 8)),
                 R04 = rep(NA, 12),
                 R05 = rep(NA, 12),
                 R06 = rep(NA, 12))
```

I know it's possible to write a function to do the matrix match and then apply it to each household with `dplyr`, however I'm not great at functions yet so I'm running into issues in a few areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the relationship matrix symmetric in each `household`, and at the same time recode the elements according to `rel`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(household) %>%
  group_modify(~ {
    mat <- as.matrix(.x[-1][1:nrow(.x)])
    mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- recode(t(mat)[upper.tri(mat)], !!!rel)
    cbind(.x[1], mat)
  }) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 × 6
   household person   R01   R02   R03   R04
       <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1         1      1    NA     1     7     7
 2         1      2     1    NA     7     7
 3         1      3     3     3    NA    11
 4         1      4     3     3    11    NA
 5         2      1    NA     7    16    NA
 6         2      2     3    NA     7    NA
 7         2      3    15     3    NA    NA
 8         3      1    NA    18    NA    NA
 9         3      2    18    NA    NA    NA
10         4      1    NA    NA    NA    NA
11         5      1    NA     9    NA    NA
12         5      2     5    NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it mostly using `base R`.

First, create `f`, a function that replace the upper triangle of a matrix with the `match`ing value from the `rel` vector and the lower triangle of the same matrix.

Then, `split` your data according to the household, compute the lengths of each group so that the resulting matrix has the right number of columns, and then apply the function to each groups. Finally, `bind_rows` and `cbind` with the original data set.

```r
f <- function(m) {
  m[upper.tri(m)] <- match(t(m)[upper.tri(m)], rel)
  m
}

l <- split(df[3:6], df$household)
len <- lapply(l, \(l) ncol(l) - (sum(sapply(l, \(x) any(!is.na(x)))) + 1))
l <- mapply(\(x, y) x[1:(length(x) - y)], l, len, SIMPLIFY = F)

cbind(df[1:2],
      dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(l, f)))
```

output

```r
   household person R01 R02 R03 R04
1          1      1  NA   1   7   7
2          1      2   1  NA   7   7
3          1      3   3   3  NA  11
4          1      4   3   3  11  NA
5          2      1  NA   7  16  NA
6          2      2   3  NA   7  NA
7          2      3  15   3  NA  NA
8          3      1  NA  18  NA  NA
9          3      2  18  NA  NA  NA
10         4      1  NA  NA  NA  NA
11         5      1  NA   9  NA  NA
12         5      2   5  NA  NA  NA
```